# How to replace a group of repeated values into one value?

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have a dataset that looks like that:

```html
i          value 
0            0
1            0
2            0
3            1           
4            1
5            1
6            0
7            0
8            0
9            0
10           0
11           0
```

There are only two outputs {0,1} each one occurs (n*3) times  back to back (consecutively) I would like to replace the three values by only one to look like the following:

```html
i          value
0            0
1            1
2            0
3            0
```

Comment: Hard to follow , there are too many edge case like 110011110000011

Comment: Sorry, let me know what isn't clear so I can clarify it more. Thanks

Comment: are they always in order and in powers of 3? if so you could just get a slice and set the step interval to 3 like so (l is your list):  `l[::3]`

Comment: @new-dev-123 yes they are always in multiples of 3; however, there might be 9 ones and then 3 zeros and then 6 ones and 12 zeros. To conclude, it isn't a must to have three zeros after/ before 3 ones

Comment: 9 consecutive ones will be replaced into 3 ones or 1 one?

Comment: @AndyL. they should be replaced by 3 ones

Comment: in that case, I guess `.iloc` with stride is enough: `df.iloc[::3].drop('i',1).reset_index(drop=True)` . This assumes your `df` has 2 columns `i` and `value` as in your sample

Answer (score 2):

If you know you always have groups of three values that are the same, you can use slice notation:

```
>>> x = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
>>> x[::3]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
```

And if you need the indices:

```
>>> list(enumerate(x[::3]))
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (3, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is your output in the form of a pandas dataframe. You can simply use slice notation in conjunction with `.iloc`. Try:

`df = df.iloc[::3].drop('i',1).reset_index(drop=True)`

Output:

```
    value
0   0
1   1
2   0
3   0
```